Reading .eeg files in python
I'm trying to read raw .eeg files in Python but haven't had much luck finding a suitable library. I've tried several libraries like [mne, neo, eegrunt, pyedflib], but none seem to support the .eeg format directly.
These .eeg files contain EEG (electroencephalogram) data recorded from a device and I need to extract and analyze the data programmatically. Could someone please suggest a Python library or method that can effectively read .eeg files?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
